# Single Column to Multiple Column Adjustable Rows and Cols AWK

Tags: awk

I have input data that looks like this in "mm/yyyy, data" format:

```
Location 1
08/2012, 44.1
09/2012, 34.2
10/2012, 24.3
11/2012, 14.4
12/2012, 04.5
01/2013, 14.6
02/2013, 24.7
Location 2
08/2012, 33.1
09/2012, 44.2
10/2012, 55.3
11/2012, 66.4
12/2012, 77.5
01/2013, 88.6
02/2013, 11.7
Location 3
08/2012, 35.1
09/2012, 45.2
10/2012, 55.3
11/2012, 66.4
12/2012, 77.5
01/2013, 71.6 
02/2013, 19.7
Location 4
etc
etc
```

and I'm using an awk script that is this -

awk '}printf (NR %276 == 0 )? $0"\n" : $0"\t" }' inputfile (I'm using NR%276 because that is the column length for each new repeating column or "Location" in the original data shown in part above).  Awk could just divide chunks of single col data from "Location X" to "Location Y" in n cols of output?

I'm getting output but it's not correct running the output from the single col input file horizontally in a text wrap fashion or "snaking" like this - Location 1 mm/yyyy, data1 data2 etc Location 2 mm/yyyy, data1 data2 etc Location 3 mm/yyyy, data1 data2 etc.

Instead, I need my output data to resemble this but for 276 rows and about 150 columns/locations or to the last single column chunk of "Location" data of 276 rows in the input file (shortened example shown above).  Would be helpful to increase the number of rows to 277 for example for 03/2013 or to >150 locations.

```
Location 1        Location 2        Location 3
08/2012, 44.1     08/2012, 33.1     08/2012, 35.1
09/2012, 34.2     09/2012, 44.2     09/2012, 45.2
10/2012, 24.3     10/2012, 55.3     10/2012, 55.3
11/2012, 14.4     11/2012, 66.4     11/2012, 66.4
12/2012, 04.5     12/2012, 77.5     12/2012, 77.5
01/2013, 14.6     01/2013, 88.6     01/2013, 71.6
02/2013, 24.7     02/2013, 11.7     02/2013, 19.7
```

Thank you!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Another awk you could try:

```
awk '!/^[0-9]/{n=0} {n++; A[n]=A[n] (A[n]?OFS:x) $0} END{for(i=1; i<=n; i++) print A[i]}' OFS='\t' file
```

---

To print only second column at each location:

```
awk '!/^[0-9]/{n=0} {n++; A[n]=A[n] (A[n]?OFS:x) $2} END{for(i=1; i<=n; i++) print A[i]}' OFS='\t' file
```

Comment: ok, it works.  i've got to figure out how to print only $2 or the second column for each "location" or column header.  any idea?  at the moment, it's printing both $1 and $2.  thanks,

Comment: @user2100039: Added quick fix

Answer (score 1):

try this one-liner:

```
 awk '/^Location/{j=0;++i}{l[i,++j]=$0}END{for(m=1;m<=j;m++){for(n=1;n<=i;n++)printf l[n,m] (n==i?"":"\t");print ""}}' file
```

**note**

- the line above transform your one-column input into 3-columns output, didn't handle your `276 rows` stuff. (I don't think we need to do that calculation.)
- in output, the columns are `tab` separated.
- row and column are not hard-coded, you could test with your real data

test with your data:

```
kent$  awk '/^Location/{j=0;++i}{l[i,++j]=$0}END{for(m=1;m<=j;m++){for(n=1;n<=i;n++)printf l[n,m] (n==i?"":"\t");print ""}}' file      
Location 1      Location 2      Location 3
08/2012, 44.1   08/2012, 33.1   08/2012, 35.1
09/2012, 34.2   09/2012, 44.2   09/2012, 45.2
10/2012, 24.3   10/2012, 55.3   10/2012, 55.3
11/2012, 14.4   11/2012, 66.4   11/2012, 66.4
12/2012, 04.5   12/2012, 77.5   12/2012, 77.5
01/2013, 14.6   01/2013, 88.6   01/2013, 71.6 
02/2013, 24.7   02/2013, 11.7   02/2013, 19.7
```

**EDIT** for comments

```
 awk '!/^[0-9]/{j=0;++i}{l[i,++j]=$0}END{for(m=1;m<=277&&m<=j;m++){for(n=1;n<=i;n++)printf l[n,m] (n==i?"":"\t");print ""}}' file
```

- the above line won't match hard-coded 'Location', but for non-number titles (works for "locations" as well)
- the 276, 277 I don't know what does it mean. but the above one-liner will for each block (location in your example), print max 276 rows. if row number less than 276, just print actual number of rows.

You can tweak a bit the one-liner, to fit your needs.

Good luck.

Comment: Sorry, col header "Location 1, etc" is for this example but in reality they are names that change so "Location" never appears in the input file.  Can it just search for any length of string instead?

Comment: in the input file, the rows of data = 276 and including the header the rows = 277. thanks again-

Comment: @user2100039 so what would be "location" in your real data? following some pattern? anyway, I think my one-liner gets you start.

Comment: names like Eagle, Westridge, MesaTop, etc.  that are unique for each chunk of header + 276 rows of data.  thanks,

Comment: there is a problem after the [0-9]/{j=0; - unterminated regexp on the { before the "j".  Ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming each location has the same number of rows of data:

```
numcols=$(tac input_file | awk '$1 == "Location" {print $2; exit}')
pr -t -s --columns=$numcols input_file
```

Since you know how many rows in each location, calculate the number of locations with:

```
numcols=$(( $(wc -l < input_file) / 277 ))
```

Comment: thanks - the "Location" headers in the actual file do not use the word "Location" but rather they are unique "locations" such as Flatiron, Wolfbog, Mesavista, etc.  Data rows are = 276 + header for each chunk of data that needs to be printed as a new column.  thanks!

Comment: glenn- i get an "illegal variable name" error when i run this code and the same error message when running the numcols code separately to find the number of locations.  Ideas?

Comment: Really? what shell do you use (bash/csh/...)? Show us the code you *actually* executed. Note the outer parentheses are doubled and the inner parentheses are single